# MacOs Bin cannot be emptied, completely empty folder structure, error shows it is used

Tags: terminal, finder, trash, ventura

So as of recently, I have problems emptying my macOS bin. It has only three elements in it: A folder named "S" and three more folders inside that folder. All those folders are empty.

I am running Ventura 13.0.1

I have tried all visual commands like empty bin or delete immediately also the basic terminal command `sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*`, nothing happens.

`sudo rm -R directory` asks me to override the rwx of the files the system thinks were in that folder, but it cannot, because all those files are gone. Therefore it returns "No such file or directory" for all those files. Ending up not deleting anything because it thinks there are locked files inside those folders.

I tried re-adding those files into the folders and then deleting them, no result.

Obviously, reinstalling macOS is always the ultimate solution but honestly who wants to do that given there is only 3 empty folders going on strike in the system? :)

Any Ideas?

@nohillside thanks a lot! This is the result of your command

```
Hi-One-MacBook-Pro:.Trash jeff$ ls -adl@Oe ~/.Trash ~/.Trash/S
ls: /Users/jeff/.Trash/S: No such file or directory
drwx------+ 2 jeff  staff  - 64 Dec 23 12:54 /Users/jeff/.Trash
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Still shows objects are in use when I try to delete them.
When I want to pull them out of the bin, it gives me Error -43

[image: This is what remains in the bin]

Comment: Can you run `ls -al@Oe ~/.Trash ~/.Trash/S` and copy/paste the result as text into the question? Please also run `cd ~/.Trash; rm -r S; sudo rm -r S` and copy/paste the result of this into the question as well.

Comment: Hi-One-MacBook-Pro:~ jeff$ ls -al@Oe ~/.Trash ~/.Trash/S
ls: /Users/jeff/.Trash/S: No such file or directory
/Users/jeff/.Trash:
total 0
ls: /Users/jeff/.Trash: Operation not permitted
Hi-One-MacBook-Pro:~ jeff$ cd ~/.Trash; rm -r S; sudo rm -r S
rm: S: No such file or directory
rm: S: No such file or directory
Hi-One-MacBook-Pro:.Trash jeff$

Comment: Uups, meant `ls -adl@Oe ~/.Trash ~/.Trash/S`. And please **edit** the question (don't add it as a comment) so the formatting is preserved.

Comment: @nohillside see update, thanks a lot

Comment: Hmm, did you try to `killall Finder` (it will restart automatically) or reboot? If the directory is empty in Terminal it might be just Finder who is confused.